# Change multiple images src with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a grid of 2 rows and 3 columns and I want a different image in each card, also the images should be different depending if the user enters from different menus.

I've tried using a for loop to select different images but only selects the first or the las ones.

```js
$("img").attr('src', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    return "media/" + currentId + i + ".jpg";
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is 1 card out of 6 -->

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title activator"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
    <span class="link">Lorem impsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-reveal">
    <span class="card-title"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
    <p>Lorem impsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I've described earlier in the post, the output should be 6 different images and it's just 6 equal images.

Comment: What is `currentId` a reference to?

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan I've forgot to explain that, it's `var currentId = this.id`
It's inside `document.ready()` and I've used it several times during the code.
I've made it a variable because I was having some trouble making it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By providing a function to `attr()` you're creating an implicit loop through every `img` element. As such you don't need the `for` loop within that function. You then can get the index of the current element in the loop by receiving the first parameter to the function and using that as the name of the image file. Try this:

```js
$("img").attr('src', function(i) {
  return "media/" + i + ".jpg";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is 1 card out of 6 -->

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator">
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
    <span class="link">Lorem impsum</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    <img class="activator">
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
    <span class="link">Lorem impsum</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set each image an `id` required for the corresponding source and using jQuery do:

```
$('.card img').each(function() {
    var path = 'media/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg'
    $(this).attr('src', path);
});
```

Comment: I thought `currentId` in his code was a pseudo for an identification to those images which he wanted to implement rather remove it. Should i delete this post?

Comment: You could be right there, that needs some clarification from the OP. No reason to delete at all :)